# Accessing Multi dimensional array object in PHP

Tags: php

I have an item object in PHP, which has the following structure on var_dump :

```
$item->properties:

array (size=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Key1' => string 'Value1' (length=6)
      'Key2' => int 1
      'Key3' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'Key4' => string 'true' (length=4)
```

I want to access Key, value in a foreach loop and assign Key, value pair to some internal variables, however when i am using the foloowing code to loop pver array of array, i am getting error in accessing the values in the way i want. Here is what i am doing :

```
        foreach($item->properties as $property) {
            foreach($property as $value) {
                echo $value;
            }
        }
```

Anyone have an idea what am i doing wrong, and how can i fix that ?

Comment: `i am getting error in accessing the values` -- what is the error?

Comment: " Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() .... "

Comment: It simply means the argument is not an array. Why do you need the nested foreach anyway? `foreach($item->properties as $property) { echo $key.' : '.$value; }` -- does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the things you provide to the foreach isn't a a valid argument, as the error says. Find out which of the 2 it is (linenumber) and var_dump that argument to see what type it is (probably "not an array" ).

In the end either `$item->properties` itself, or the array values of that array (if it is one), so `$property` is not an array.

It could be, for instance, that maybe the first key of the properties IS an array, but the second isn't? then you could use `is_array` to check.